Managing STM32 STM32CubeIDE Projects
I am working on STM32 Projects with STM32CubeIDE. On creating project with STM32CubeIDE and after generating code, I got all these files as in image below. I now want to manage these projects and files over Github.


Which Infos I must provide to Other contributors to the Project? For e.g.: STM32CubeIDE version, and what else?
What to share and what not to share to the Github? What should I may be include in the .gitignore file?
Which files are necessary for the project? Which files I can delete, may be it is automatically generated every time for example while building project?
Any more tips for managing these kinds of Project through Github?

I will really appreciate your answers. Thank you in advance.

From the files that you show, you should add .settings/ to your .gitignore. It contains personal settings that other developers might not share.
Add Debug/ to your .gitignore. If you ever make a release build, then add Release/ to your .gitignore. These contain build output (e.g. .o files, binaries, etc), and you don't want to add that to your repo.
If you ever run your code in the debugger, you will get some *.launch files, which should also be ignored. They are linked to your exact setup (e.g. ST-Link serial numbers) and are not common to other developers.
Everything else is essential and should be part of the repo, and can be shared. Don't start deleting files.
